# How to get category in checkout cart in opencart?

Tags: opencart, checkout, opencart2.x, opencart-module

first at all thanks for the help... Im new on opencart, hope somebody can help me...

Im getting crazy trying to find the answer in google for my question...

I wanna add the category name in checkout/cart

```
<a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a>
```

I try to add a new variable in the controller of cart.pl, but is impossible, as the answer that i found in internet doesnt work...

BTW i work on Opencart 2.2.0...

this is what i have in cart.pl on my template:

```
<?php foreach ($products as $product) { ?>      

                <div class="gry_part">
                        <div class="width1">

                        <a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a> - 
                        <a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><?php echo $product['name']; ?></a>

                        <?php if (!$product['stock']) { ?>
                          <span class="stock">***</span>
                        <?php } ?>

                        <div>
                            <?php foreach ($product['option'] as $option) { ?>
                            - <small><?php echo $option['name']; ?>: <?php echo $option['value']; ?></small><br />
                            <?php } ?>
                            <?php if($product['recurring']): ?>
                            - <small><?php echo $text_payment_profile ?>: <?php echo $product['profile_name'] ?></small>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                          </div>
                          <?php if ($product['reward']) { ?>
                          <small><?php echo $product['reward']; ?></small>
                          <?php } ?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="width2 quantity">
                            <input type="text" name="quantity[<?php echo $product['cart_id']; ?>]" value="<?php echo $product['quantity']; ?>" size="1" />
                            <input type="image" src="catalog/view/theme/amishop/image/update.png" alt="<?php echo $button_update; ?>" title="<?php echo $button_update; ?>" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="width3"><?php echo $product['price']; ?></div>
                        <div class="width4">
                        <button type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $button_remove; ?>" class="add_to99" onclick="cart.remove('<?php echo $product['cart_id']; ?>');">Delete</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>

        <?php } ?>
```

and this is what i try to add in the controller cart.pl

```
$categories = $this->model_catalog_product->getCategories($product_id);
        if ($categories)
            $categories_info = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategory($categories[0]['category_id']);
        $this->data['category_title'] = $categories_info['name'];
```

sorry for this, if is quite stupid question, but im new on this...

thanks for all..

Comment: So you want to display category, next to category column on shopping cart page ?

Comment: next to "Product" column in shopping cart page, yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following [Source : A2bizz blogs](http://blog.a2bizz.com/index.php/2016/05/18/product-category-on-cart-page-in-opencart-2-2-0-0/)

> Create an OCMOD file - category_on_cart.ocmod.xml

Copy following code and save it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<modification>
    <name>Category_Cart</name>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <code>Category_Cart</code>
    <author>A2bizz</author>
    <link>http://blog.a2bizz.com</link>
    <file path="catalog/view/theme/*/template/checkout/cart.tpl">
        <operation>
            <search><![CDATA[
           <td class="text-left"><?php echo $column_name; ?></td>
            ]]></search>
            <add position="after" offset="0"><![CDATA[
            <td class="text-left"><?php echo $column_category; ?></td>
            ]]></add>
        </operation>
         <operation>
            <search><![CDATA[
           <td class="text-left"><?php echo $product['model']; ?></td>
            ]]></search>
            <add position="before" offset="0"><![CDATA[
            <td class="text-left"><?php echo $product['category_name']; ?></td>
            ]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>
    <file path="catalog/controller/checkout/cart.php">
        <operation>
            <search><![CDATA[
           $data['column_name'] = $this->language->get('column_name');
            ]]></search>
            <add position="after" offset="0"><![CDATA[
            $data['column_category'] = $this->language->get('column_category');
            ]]></add>
        </operation>
         <operation>
            <search><![CDATA[
           $this->load->model('tool/upload');
            ]]></search>
            <add position="after" offset="0"><![CDATA[
            $this->load->model('catalog/custom');
            ]]></add>
        </operation>
        <operation>
            <search><![CDATA[
           $product_total = 0;
            ]]></search>
            <add position="before" offset="0"><![CDATA[
            $category_name = $this->model_catalog_custom->getproductcategory($product['product_id']);
            ]]></add>
        </operation>
        <operation>
            <search><![CDATA[
           'name'      => $product['name'],
            ]]></search>
            <add position="after" offset="0"><![CDATA[
            'category_name'=>$category_name,
            ]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>
     <file path="catalog/language/*/checkout/cart.php">
        <operation>
            <search><![CDATA[
           $_['column_name']              = 'Product Name';
            ]]></search>
            <add position="after" offset="0"><![CDATA[
            $_['column_category']              = 'Product Category';
            ]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>
</modification>
```

> Create catalog/model/catalog/custom.php

add following code in this file.

```
<?php
class ModelCatalogCustom extends Model {
    public function getproductcategory($product_id){
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_category WHERE product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "'");
        $category = $this->getCategory($query->row['category_id']);
        return $category['name'];
    }

    public function getCategory($category_id) {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT DISTINCT *, (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(cd1.name ORDER BY level SEPARATOR '&nbsp;&nbsp;&gt;&nbsp;&nbsp;') FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "category_path cp LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "category_description cd1 ON (cp.path_id = cd1.category_id AND cp.category_id != cp.path_id) WHERE cp.category_id = c.category_id AND cd1.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "' GROUP BY cp.category_id) AS path, (SELECT DISTINCT keyword FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "url_alias WHERE query = 'category_id=" . (int)$category_id . "') AS keyword FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "category c LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "category_description cd2 ON (c.category_id = cd2.category_id) WHERE c.category_id = '" . (int)$category_id . "' AND cd2.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "'");

        return $query->row;
    }
}
```

Now go to the `Admin dashboard -> Extensions -> Extension installer` to install the `category_on_Cart.ocmod.xml` file.

After that go to the `Admin dashboard-> Extensions->Modifications` to refresh cache. Click on refresh buttton first button on right corner.

[image]